# How to link an external image of the current project into a view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How to link an external image of the current project into a View page into an ASP.NET MVC 4 project?

```
<img src="../../imgs/a.png" alt="404!"/>
```

For example, here I'm trying to display `a.png` which is placed under the second parent folder of the current project. But, doing this, I get an blank/corrupted image.

How do I to display that photo, please?

Answer (score 0):

The image URL is resolved by the browser.

If the URL starts with `..` it will be relative to the page that is loading it.
If the URL is relative to the application root, it will start with `/`.

If the page location, for example, is `http://localhost:666/` then the browser will not be able to resolve the url `../imgs/a.png`.

Therefore, you got 2 options:

**Option 1:** in order to present an image that is not stored in the application folder, you will need to create a Controller/Action that will read the image from the file system and send it to browser.

Something like this:

```
public ActionResult MyImage()
{
     var filePath = "C:\\imgs\\a.png";

     if (File.Exists(filePath))
     {
         var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

         return File(fileContent, "image/*");
     }
}
```

And then on your page: `<img src="@Url.Action("MyImage","MyController")" alt="404!" />`

**Option 2:** Create a "Virtual Directory" in your IIS application. See explanation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I've written `/ProjectName/../../imgs/a.png` but this still the same and I've also tried `/../../imgs/a.png`. But, without any result.

Comment: @user3472134 - the IIS will not be able to resolve the requested URL. I added couple of possible solutions to my answer.

Comment: Of course, if you have the option to move the `imgs` folder into the MVC application, it will be the easiest solution.

Comment: It's a method inside the `Controller` that returns `FileContentResult `: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Url.Content`

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/imgs/a.png")" />
```